# How can I use binary_cross_entropy in binary classification in Chainer

Tags: conv-neural-network, predict, chainer

I have train dataset of 8000 images and labels. Validation set consists of 1957 images and labels. The test set contains 2487 images. Each image contains White Blood Cell images. WBC is divided innto 4 categories: Eosinophil, Neutrophil, Monocyte and Lymphocyte. Eosinophil and Neutrophil are Polynuclear while the remaining two are Mononuclear. The cells need to be classified between the two classes : Polynuclear and Mononuclear.

```
# import libraries
def get_data(folder):
    X = []
    y = []

    for wbc_type in os.listdir(folder):
        if not wbc_type.startswith('.'):
            if wbc_type in ['NEUTROPHIL', 'EOSINOPHIL']:
                label = 'POLYNUCLEAR'
            else:
                label = 'MONONUCLEAR'
            for image_filename in tqdm(os.listdir(folder + wbc_type)):
                img_file = cv2.imread(folder + wbc_type + '/' + image_filename)
                if img_file is not None:
                # Downsample the image to 120, 160, 3
                    img_file = scipy.misc.imresize(arr=img_file, size=(120, 160, 3))
                    img_arr = np.asarray(img_file)
                    X.append(img_arr)
                    y.append(label)
    X = np.asarray(X)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    return X,y

X_train, y_train = get_data('C:/Users/Neerajan/Desktop/blood-cells/dataset2-master/dataset2-master/images/TRAIN/')
X_test, y_test = get_data('C:/Users/Neerajan/Desktop/blood-cells/dataset2-master/dataset2-master/images/TEST/')

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
y_train = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)

X_train=np.array((X_train), dtype = np.float32)
X_train=X_train/255.0

X_test=np.array((X_test), dtype = np.float32)
X_test=X_test/255.0

y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_train = y_train.flatten()

from chainer.datasets import split_dataset_random
from chainer.dataset import DatasetMixin

class MyDataset(DatasetMixin):
    def __init__(self, X, labels):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()
        self.X_ = X
        self.labels_ = labels
        self.size_ = X.shape[0]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size_

    def get_example(self, i):
        return np.transpose(self.X_[i, ...], (2, 0, 1)), self.labels_[i]

batch_size = 32

dataset = MyDataset(X_train, y_train)
dataset_train, valid = split_dataset_random(dataset, 8000, seed=0)
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(dataset_train, batch_size)
valid_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(valid, batch_size, repeat=False, shuffle=False)

from chainer.dataset import concat_examples

batch_image, batch_label = concat_examples(next(train_iter))
print("batch_image.shape\n{}".format(batch_image.shape))
print("batch_label.shape\n{}".format(batch_label.shape))
```

batch_image.shape : (32,3,120,160) batch_label.shape : (32,)

```
class MyModel(chainer.Chain):

def __init__(self, n_out):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    with self.init_scope():
        self.conv1=L.Convolution2D(None, 32, 3, 3, 1)
        self.conv2=L.Convolution2D(32, 64, 3, 3, 1)
        self.conv3=L.Convolution2D(64, 128, 3, 3, 1)
        self.fc4=L.Linear(None, 32)
        self.fc5=L.Linear(32, n_out)

def __call__(self, x):
    h = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
    h = F.relu(self.conv2(h))
    h = F.relu(self.conv3(h))
    h = F.leaky_relu(self.fc4(h))
    h = F.sigmoid(self.fc5(h))
    return h

from chainer import training
def train(model_object, batchsize=32, gpu_id=-1, max_epoch=14):

    model = L.Classifier(model_object)
    if gpu_id >=0:
        model.to_gpu(gpu_id)

    #serializers.save_npz('kankata',model)
    # 4. Optimizer
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
    optimizer.setup(model)

    serializers.save_npz('my.state',optimizer)
    # 5. Updater
    updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=gpu_id)

    # 6. Trainer
    trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (max_epoch, 'epoch'), out='C:/Users/Neerajan/Desktop/ReportDump'.format(model_object.__class__.__name__))

    # 7. Evaluator

    class TestModeEvaluator(extensions.Evaluator):

        def evaluate(self):
            model = self.get_target('main')
            ret = super(TestModeEvaluator, self).evaluate()
            return ret

    trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport())
    trainer.extend(TestModeEvaluator(valid_iter, model, device=gpu_id))
    trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'main/loss', 'main/accuracy', 'validation/main/loss', 'validation/main/accuracy', 'elapsed_time']))
    trainer.extend(extensions.PlotReport(['main/loss', 'validation/main/loss'], x_key='epoch', file_name='loss.png'))
    trainer.extend(extensions.PlotReport(['main/accuracy', 'validation/main/accuracy'], x_key='epoch', file_name='accuracy.png'))
    trainer.run()
    del trainer


    return model

gpu_id = -1  # Set to -1 if you don't have a GPU

model = train(MyModel(2), gpu_id=gpu_id)
```

It is recommended that for binary classification we use sigmoid activation function in the last layer of model and binary_cross_entropy in classifier.

How do I implement binary_cross_entropy as the loss_function in the classifier?

Answer (score 1):

see [this example](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/tree/master/examples/glance) for binary classification.

```
 43 model = L.Classifier(
 44     MLP(44, 1), lossfun=F.sigmoid_cross_entropy, accfun=F.binary_accuracy)
```

feeding `lossfun=F.sigmoid_cross_entropy` to `L.Classifier` is a good solution.

Comment: Do I need to add sigmoid activation in the last layer of my model?

Comment: Changing lossfun and accfun and changing output layer to 1 in last line(model = train(MyModel(1), gpu_id=gpu_id)) gives  the error:                               InvalidType: 
Invalid operation is performed in: SigmoidCrossEntropy (Forward)

Expect: x.shape == t.shape
Actual: (32, 1) != (32,)

Comment: the output of your model should be (32,), not (32, 1). You only have to `F.squeeze()`.